# Is LIBGDX Slower in python than Java

Tags: java, python, performance, libgdx, jython-2.7

I've been developing games in Python & Pygame for a while now, Though one thing that's been in mind is my dislike to pygame's performance and lack of tools and libraries.

I've always known LibGDX for it's popularity and how much I've seen it on this site. Though recently I found out that it supports JVM Languages so that I can use it with python under the Jpython interpreter.

Since I have more knowledge on using python, I'm planning on learning LibGDX for it. Though I already know a decent amount of Java and it wouldn't be an incredibly extra amount of work If I we're to just finish learning more Java.

Though I do prefer Python for how much I've been working in it.

**What I'm asking**

I was wondering if there was any downsides to using LibGDX In python (JPython) instead of it's main and popular language Java. One that comes to mind are performance issues, would it be slower to develop with LibGDX in Jython than in Java? Another that comes to mind would be cross-platform exportation, are you unable to export to android or IOS using Python(Jython)?

Anybody really knowledge on LibGDX or Jython & LibGDX be able to answer this?

Comment: Mostly unrelated, but when making games with Pygame, the thread library is your friend.  I managed to get my framerate up to 60 fps with some very complicated games by multithreading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have a hard time finding examples of Jython + LibGDX. I would guess it would also be hard to find many people here on SO that have any experience with Jython + LibGDX.

Another issue is cross platform development. Jython might use JVM, but android does not give you JVM. I don't know how well Jython works with Dalvik.
If I remember correctly LibGDX uses Intel Multi-OS Engine for iOS. I have no idea how that works with Jython. In any case, getting help will be hard.

When it comes to performance of Jython + LibGDX vs. java + LibGDX I don't think there is a big difference. On desktop that is, it might not even work on other platforms.

If you want to develop for desktop only, don't need help and is fine with only seeing java examples and tutorials then I would say go for it. 
In any other case go with java. The time and energy you would need learning Jython + LibGDX would be much better spend learning java + LibGDX.